# Java code to process special characters that need to be replaced by other special characters

Tags: java, string, special-characters

I am writing Java code to process a string received from a Mainframe that contains special characters that need to be replaced by other special characters, my search characters are `§ÄÖÜäüßö@[\]~{¦}` and the replacement characters  are `@[\]{}~¦§ÄÖÜßäöü` so if the string has a `{` in it I need to replace it with `ä` and example of my input is `"0.201322.05.2017LM-R{der Dopp"`

My code currently is

```
        String repChar = "§ÄÖÜäüßö@[\\\\]~{¦}@[\\\\]{}~¦§ÄÖÜßäöü";
        // Split String and Convert
        String repCharin = repChar.substring(0, repChar.length()/2-1);
        String repCharout = repChar.substring(repChar.length()/2, repChar.length()-1);          
        String strblob = new String(utf8ContentIn);
        // Convert  
        for (int j=0; j < repCharin.length();j++) {
            strblob = strblob.replace(repCharin.substring(j, 1), repCharout.substring(j, 1));                               
        }
        byte [] utf8Content = strblob.getBytes();
```

But it generates the following error

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException     at
>   java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1240)

The \\ are escaped characters I only need a single \

Comment: You're getting the error because you're looping through via the length of a string whilst changing the string.

Comment: which line throws exception?  what i can say is `strblob = strblob.replace(repCharin.substring(j, 1), repCharout.substring(j, 1));` might be `strblob = strblob.replace(repCharin.substring(j, j+1), repCharout.substring(j, j+1));`

Comment: I would suggest getting the byte(s) representation of those characters and work completely in byte-mode gather than using String manipilation. Remember some characters encoded with mulitple bytes.

Comment: The `.substring` calls which initialize `repCharin` and `repCharout` are both wrong--they extract strings one character too short.  You should jettison that nonsense and just initialize `repCharin` and `repCharout` directly with the correct string literals, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
    String utf8ContentIn = "0.201322.05.2017LM-R{der Dopp";

    String repChar = "§ÄÖÜäüßö@[\\]~{¦}@[\\]{}~¦§ÄÖÜßäöü";
    // Split String and Convert
    String repCharin = repChar.substring(0, repChar.length() / 2);
    String repCharout = repChar.substring(repChar.length() / 2, repChar.length());
    String strblob = new String(utf8ContentIn);

    String output = strblob.chars().mapToObj(c -> {
        char ch = (char) c;
        int index = repCharin.indexOf(c);
        if (index != -1) {
            ch = repCharout.charAt(index);
        }
        return String.valueOf(ch);
    }).collect(Collectors.joining());

    System.out.println(output);
```

will print `"0.201322.05.2017LM-Räder Dopp"` as you expect. Your problem here (besides incorrect indexes during separation) is that you should iterate input string instead of your characters. Because you can run into situation when you replace `Ä` with `[` and after threat `[` as special character again and replace it second time with `Ä`.

Also, single backslash should be escaped with single backslash, so to get `\` you need `\\`

Hope it helps!